# Can not load file using PHPExcel

Tags: file-upload, phpexcel, file-read

I am currently using PHPExcel library to read my excel file which is to be uploaded by user . But I can not load the uploaded file.
I am using this code, i cannot get the file path right at this moment and if there is some one who could tell me , what to write in load portion => $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load();
The uploaded file is being transferred to the folder named "upload".

```
<?php
$storagename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$new_file_name=$storagename.'.xlsx';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" . $new_file_name);
include ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php"); 
$html="<table border='1'>";
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('"../upload/" . $new_file_name');  

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();  
    for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)  
    {
      $html.="<tr>";  
      $site_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());  
      $solution_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());  

      $html.= '<td>'.$site_name.'</td>';  
      $html .= '<td>'.$solution_type.'</td>';
      $html .= "</tr>";
      }  
    }  
    $html .= '</table>';  
    echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: i dont understand the '$upload_file'   you are not setting it as far as i can see and why the ''..... what if you change it with the ""../upload/" . $new_file_name" that you used for the move_uploaded_file

Comment: `'$upload_file'` is a string literal..... simply remove the quotes to treat it as a variable

Comment: it was a mistake. I am not using $upload_file variable. instead using "../upload/" . $new_file_name . see my edited code. but it does not work. please help.

Comment: is the file that you uploaded also showing in the upload folder.... and did you test this code with a file by just hardcoding a excel file you know that exist?

Comment: and what does your error log say, normally your error log can show some useful info

Comment: yes, uploaded file is showing in the upload folder. problem start when it start to load it. Instead of uploading code, this code can load any specific file & echo the content. bt it can not load the uploaded file.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with msg 'Could nt opn "../upload/" . $new_file_name for reading! File does not exist.' in  C:\xampp\htdocs\casper\admin\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:82 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\casper\admin\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(280): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->canRead('"../upload/" . ...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\casper\admin\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('"../upload/" . ...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\casper\admin\test.php(116): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('"../upload/" . ...') #3 {main} thrown

Comment: i would have expected NOT to see the var name in your error log, maybe dont quote your var and just keep it like "../upload/" . $new_file_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working to load file usinh PHPExcel.

```
<?php
$storagename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$new_file_name=$storagename.'.xlsx';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../upload/" .$new_file_name);
$upload_file = "../upload/" . $new_file_name;

include ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php"); 
$html="<table border='1'>";
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($upload_file);  

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();  
for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)  
{
  $html.="<tr>";  
  $site_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());  
  $solution_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());  

  $html.= '<td>'.$site_name.'</td>';  
  $html .= '<td>'.$solution_type.'</td>';
  $html .= "</tr>";
  }  
}  
$html .= '</table>';  
echo $html;
?>
```